# How do I get the access token explicitly in the Facebook API for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I downloaded the Facebook iPhone demo app recently.  I have made several attempts to grasp the authentication process and I'm totally confused.  There seems to be a lot of sample code out there that has been rendered obsolete in this version of the API.

In the .m file for my primary view controller, I have the following at the start:

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
```

The button that requires information from Facebook uses this line, unchanged from the demo app:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

This calls the following method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
```

I have hacked my functionality into this method.  I pull a few things I need from Facebook and send them to my backend in a HTTP POST command. For example, [result objectForKey:@"id"] returns the id and [result objectForKey:@"name"] returns the name.  However, [result objectForKey:@"access_token"] returns nothing.  This is very frustrating because I need to pass the access token to my Google App Engine user management back end to create a new user.  So, hopefully the code I have included makes my authetication strategy clear (whatever it is).  Does anyone know how I can get the access token in this context?  I would appreciate it if you could help me out with what header files I need to have included etc. ?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing the same exact thing you are. I'm making my own HTTP requests, so I need the accessToken, and what's more, the iOS Facebook SDK doesn't remember the accessToken past launches, even with a no-expire request!

After calling [_facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self]; In the fbDidLogin delegate call, you can easily pull (assuming you have the facebook object retained in _facebook):

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSString *accessToken = _facebook.accessToken;
NSDate *expirationDate = _facebook.expirationDate;
}
```

Voilà.

To handle persistence through app launches, you can save this data and manually set those accessors prior to any requests.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for your help.  That worked perfectly.  I have an embarassing follow-on question.  I can NSLog accessToken within FBDidLogin and it works.  However, within my later call to the method `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {`, the variable accessToken is unrecognized.  How do I move the variable between the two methods?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Thanks for your help Daniel.  That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

after success full login you can retrieve using,

```
[[FBSession activeSession] accessToken];
```