# How to generate acces token on Facebook through iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-oauth

I need to generate access token for particular Facebook account through app on iPhone. Please give some guidelines to start this work.

Comment: Open Facebook.com-->login-->click on developers tag-->iOS SDK-->Find out Register an app-->After registering the app at that portal will give you the access token

Answer (score 1):

You can get access token by this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYID&client_secret=*MY_SECRET*&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Access token granted by user have expiration time. If token expired then you need to request it again. But if you ask user to grant you "offline_access" permissions then you'll have almost not limited access token. You can store it in database or file and use next time.

You can see this questions:

- [How to get a Facebook access token on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016405/how-to-get-a-facebook-access-token-on-ios)
- [How do I get the access token explicitly in the Facebook API for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698436/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-explicitly-in-the-facebook-api-for-iphone)